# How to convert a MAC address (in string) to array of integers?

Tags: c, arrays, string

How do I convert a MAC address within a string to an array of integers in *C*?

For example, I have the following string that stores a MAC address:

> 00:0d:3f:cd:02:5f

How do I convert this to:

```
uint8_t array[6] = {0x00, 0x0d, 0x3f, 0xcd, 0x02, 0x5f}
```

Answer (score 28):

```
uint8_t bytes[6];
int values[6];
int i;

if( 6 == sscanf( mac, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x%*c",
    &values[0], &values[1], &values[2],
    &values[3], &values[4], &values[5] ) )
{
    /* convert to uint8_t */
    for( i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
        bytes[i] = (uint8_t) values[i];
}

else
{
    /* invalid mac */
}
```

[EDIT: Added `%c` at the end of the format string to reject excess characters in the input, based on D Krueger's suggestion.]

Comment: You can also add a %c on the end of the format string to ensure there are no extraneous characters after the sixth octet.

Comment: @DKrueger Thanks, good suggestion... edited accordingly.

Comment: According to Linux man page, "If the number of conversion specifications in format exceeds the number of pointer arguments, the results are undefined." So best to add a pointer to a char as the last param to sscanf()

Comment: To add on top of that: use `%hhx` instead of `%x` to avoid the `for()` loop. This is going to make it possible to replace `values[]` with `bytes[]` in `sscanf()`. I also think you need some storage for the final `%c`.

Comment: %c in the example doesn't have a suitable variable, which causes segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks, changed to `%*c` so that it doesn't try to store the result of the conversion anywhere.

Comment: `%*c` makes it broken, since that makes it return 6 even if there are trailing characters. You need that dummy variable, I think.

Comment: This answer will also accept `1:2:3:444:555:666`. Should be `%2x` instead of `%x`.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the few places where I'd consider using something like *sscanf()* to parse the string, since MAC addresses tend to be formatted very rigidly:

```
char str[] = "00:0d:3f:cd:02:5f";
uint8_t mac_addr[6];
if (sscanf(str, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x",
           &mac_addr[0],
           &mac_addr[1],
           &mac_addr[2],
           &mac_addr[3],
           &mac_addr[4],
           &mac_addr[5]) < 6)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "could not parse %s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: Not safe and will generate warnings in some compilers, because you're passing pointers to type `uint8_t`, which is almost certainly not as wide as `int` which is what `sscanf()` is expecting.